# Connecting SQL Server to laravel as a second database

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have laravel 5.8 setup and working with MySQL. I need to connect a second database (SQL Server).

I have the following in my .env file

```
DB_EXT_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_EXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_EXT_PORT=1433
DB_EXT_DATABASE=database
DB_EXT_USERNAME=user
DB_EXT_PASSWORD=password
```

database.php

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env(''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

I am running xampp and have the following dll's installed

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
```

I keep getting

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Protocol error in TDS stream (SQL:select * from [dbo].[t_people]) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs
```

I have

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('dbo.t_people')->select('*')->get();
```

in my blade template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all the `DB_DATABASE` from your config file to `DB_EXT_DATABASE`, as you wrote in your `.env` file. 
Try instead of

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('dbo.t_people')->select('*')->get();
```

do the

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('t_people')->select('*')->get();
```

And don't do it in your blade files, do it in controller.